# How to use Progress dialog in Application class in android studio

Tags: android, database, class, progress, extends

i have a class named myApp which extends Application class in android studio

i mean each and every app starting time need to call data from local side

let's say example i have 100's of data in local side..this data must be need to call every time when app starts

for that created one class named as myApp extends Application

so i can call every app open time

so here i'm calling data retrieving methods.

but user need to know that thing like data is loading background..

so i want to use progress dialog in this application class

```
      public class myApp extends Application {

      Context mContext;


      //so i used like this 

     //1 st way

  mContext = getApplicationContext();

  ProgressDialog dialog=ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "Data", 
  "Synching");
  dialog.show();

  //2 nd way

  mContext = this;

  ProgressDialog dialog=ProgressDialog.show(mContext, "Data", 
  "Synching");
  dialog.show();

  //3 rd way

 ProgressDialog dialog=ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), 
 "Data", 
  "Synching");
  dialog.show();

 //4 th way

 ProgressDialog dialog=ProgressDialog.show((myApp.this, "Data", 
  "Synching");
  dialog.show();

  }
```

its giving this exception.

```
     android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add 
     window -- token null is not for an application
```

i tried these ways but i failed

all cases failed....

so how can i show progress dialog when data getting time after completing data how to close progress dialog

thanks in advance

Comment: You should consider rewriting your answer, honestly I coudln't figure out what are you talking about, except for a few words. From what I can understand, you need to retrieve data showing the progress: the usual procedure is to create a custom AsyncTask, load the data in doInBackground and publish a progress update for onProgressUpdate. Then, once finished, you can stop the dialog with onPostExecute.

Comment: Please try to enhance the formatting of the question and also the formulation of your sentences.

Comment: simply i'm saying 

i want to use progress dialog in application class 

i tried those ways what i mentioned in the question

can you provide me answer now

Answer (score 0):

In place of this doing like this you can create a SuperActivity for all your sub-activities

```
class SuperActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
// here you can put you data which is common for all activities
    public void showProgressBar(){
        // write your code here to show progress bar
    }
    public void hideProgressBar(){
        // write your code here to dismiss progress bar
    }
}
class Activity1 extends SuperActivity{
}
class Activity2 extends SuperActivity{
}
class Activity3 extends SuperActivity{
}
```

Comment: see this  is my class

public class MyApplication extends Application {

//here i should use progress bar...because i explained my scenario on above
}

Comment: dont use application class for your data, use superActivity, whatever the approach you are using is wrong, you cannot update from ui elements from application class

Answer (score -1):

Yes It is possible to use ProgressDialog in Application class

```
   public class ApplicationClass extends Application {
    ProgressDialog pd;
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this.getApplicationContext(),R.style.MyTheme);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.setProgressStyle(android.R.style.Widget_ProgressBar_Small);
        pd.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        pd.show();
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

Comment: Does not work on Android 6.0.1 `Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@3ba724e -- permission denied for this window type`. And yes, I added the permission.